# Swift How do I stop the tab bar from changing background colors

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tabbar

I'm working on a project that requires a Tabbar. Currently I have my code set up so that after login or sign up I'm presented by the Explore tab (The third tab). The goal I'm trying to achieve is to have my project only show a translucent tab bar background. When I was originally working on my project I had no issue doing this. I ran in the problem after I incorporated a table view that allow for scrolling. Currently when ever I push on the tab 1-4 I get a translucent background. When tab 5 (includes the table view with scrolling) is pressed the background of the tab bar changes to a gray color. Even if I press out of the tab to a different one the gray tab bar background color doesn't change. The only way I found to dismiss the back ground color after the 5th tab has been selected is to scroll all the way down. After I'm scrolled down it allows the user to see the translucent background again. Then you can select different tab bars and you'll see the translucent background again. How do I only show a translucent color

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to unindent the images at the end, because MarkDown thinks they’re a code block.

Comment: Tab bar now has multiple appearances. You need to use those. Start with https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarappearance and go from there.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set Bar-Tint colour to Default. [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKkhV.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).